# Defining the amount of elements in an array

Tags: c++

I was wondering if I do this:

```
int TOPE , vector[TOPE] ;
cin >> TOPE ;
```

Does vector get the amount of elements I input or does it have a number that I can't control?

Comment: How is this question related with C#?

Comment: **No**. Neither has C++ support for variable length arrays, and even your compiler has this feature, it will not resize the array after initializing.

Comment: You won't be able to make an arbitrary sized array, only something predefined (from a constant or a literal). Use `std::vector` for dynamic arrays

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The variable `vector` is a *Variable-Length Array (VLA)*. Standard C++ doesn't support that, but some compiler supports that as extension.

The variable `TOPE` is not initialized at the point where the variable `vector` is declared, so its size is indeterminate.

To set the size of VLA to the number entered, you should write like this:

```
int TOPE;
cin >> TOPE ;
int vector[TOPE] ;
```

To do it in more standard way, you should use [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead of VLA:

```
int TOPE;
cin >> TOPE ;
std::vector<int> vector(TOPE);
```

Comment: If use 
`#define TOPE 10` 
is TOPE still a variable or would it work that way?

Comment: `#define` is like a string replacement. Using that, `TOPE` will be replaced with `10` and it is no longer a variable.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, `VLA`s, or variable-length array is not a C++ standard, although some compiler like `gcc` does support it. More info : [Why aren't variable-length arrays part of the C++ standard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard)

Secondly, compilers read in a top-down fashion. Changing a variable after it has been used as length for an array isn't going to change the array in any way.

To declare it properly, declare it like this :

```
int TOPE; std::cin >> TOPE;
int vector[TOPE];
```